# Speed up the search process in a big amount of data?

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, search

I have a SQLite (v3) database with following example table:

5 columns ("FirstName", "LastName", "Street", ZIPCode, "City")
more than 1'100'000 rows

I'm looking for the fastest method in VB.NET to find an entered search string in the entire data. This entered search string should match the complete content of a field OR only a part of it.

So far, I try to load the whole data into a datatable (takes about 40 seconds). Then I try to search with this SQL command:

```
dt.Select("FirstName LIKE '%" + SearchString + "%'")
```

In my other method, I create a sorted DataView and search with the RowFilter command:

```
dvSORTED.RowFilter = "FirstName LIKE '%" & SearchString & "%'"
```

The first method returns smaller amounts of results (~100) within 1,1 seconds, the second method needs 1,5 seconds.

This is true for a search in a single column. For every additional column, the search time will be multiplied by the above time. A search in all columns needs about 8 seconds (5 x 1,5).

Little comparison: If I execute this SQL command directly in SQLiteSpy

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Street, ZIPCode, City FROM Addresses WHERE FirstName LIKE "%Peter%" or LastName LIKE "%Peter%" or Street LIKE "%Peter%" or City LIKE "%Peter%"
```

then I have to wait about 10 seconds for the result.

How can I speed up the search process in all the available data?

Comment: Do you really need to search in the middle of words? [FTS](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) would be able to do prefix searches.

Comment: Don't load all the values in a data table. If you only need part of it then do the query on the database side.

Comment: Is the database/are the tables indexed??  I thought indexing made 90% of database engines much faster.  [In which case, like @the_lotus says, use the DB engine to do the work].

Comment: @CL: Yes. The database itself is provided by a customer software solution. I can't make changes to the database itself.

Comment: @the_lotus: I need a search over all the existing data.

Comment: @Grim: Would an index help for a "LIKE" search too?

Comment: @Grim Indexes would help only for prefix searches. (And FTS helps only with word prefixes.)

Comment: If you can't modify the database, then I guess it's back to the original question!  If the data is rarely changing, but your searches are running often, can't you create a 'local buffer' in your code - I'm pretty sure searching arrays/collections/lists would be quicker in most situations.  Granted, I don't think I've had a List(Of String) with over a million items in before!

Comment: @Grim As I wrote, I already use a 'local buffer', a datatable in my case. Do you know anything faster? What exactly would you suggest?

Comment: I don't have a million rows of anything handy, but this kind of thing interests me!  For the short data - i.e. your names - have you tried buffering them into lists of string, then doing a search on the list?  Try that and see what kind of times you get.  I notice there's no `ID` column or similar, which makes it kind of tricky.
I'm wondering if it's the `DataTable` that's slowing you down and building your own skeleton object would be quicker.  Gimme half an hour and I'll have a play...

Comment: OK, I've written something that generates 1.2 million sets of data and stores them in a basic class object - that takes under 5 seconds.  I then do a simple LINQ expression to find `bob` in the `.First` property of the data class, and that finds (e.g.) 240 records in also under 4 seconds.  So initial feeling is that the datatable is the fastest!

Comment: Because I've used LINQ and AndAlso in my query, doing a search on multiple columns is actually quicker than just one!  A four column search is taking about 2.5 seconds at the moment, so I think it's going to be a trade off depending on how often you search multiple columns, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting all of the strings you need to search in a single string and ask if it `contains` the value you are looking for. Here are my test results with 1.7M records (fairly unique):

```
If DT.Select("street like '%" & SearchString& "%'").Count > 0 Then
```

This took about 11 seconds to run

If I put all my values into a string with a pike "|" separator and then ran

```
If StringToSearch.Contains(SearchString) then...
```

This took about 20ms. Even the time to put all the strings into a single string only took 2 seconds so I could reload the `StringToSearch` every time and still be faster than the SELECT. I wasn't even using a `StringBuilder`. But, if you can keep the variable 'StringToSearch' around, and not rebuild it everytime, it will be way faster.

BTW, iterating through the rows and asking each field if it contains the value took 1.5 seconds:

```
If dr("street").ToString.Contains(SearchString) Then
```

Lastly, I did try Regex but is was the same time as `Contains`.